# compressing string in js and save in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save a HUGE json string in my localStorage but for some reason sometimes it saves it and sometimes not, I thought I should compress it so I took an `LZW implementation` in js from one of the threads in stackoverflow.

The problem is when I try to `localStorage.setItem()` the compressed string it gives me an error "`Invalid argument`", any idea why or what should I do?

Edit:

this is the code I'm using:

```
// LZW-compress a string
function lzw_encode(s) {
    var dict = {};
    var data = (s + "").split("");
    var out = [];
    var currChar;
    var phrase = data[0];
    var code = 256;
    for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
        currChar=data[i];
        if (dict[phrase + currChar] != null) {
            phrase += currChar;
        }
        else {
            out.push(phrase.length > 1 ? dict[phrase] : phrase.charCodeAt(0));
            dict[phrase + currChar] = code;
            code++;
            phrase=currChar;
        }
    }
    out.push(phrase.length > 1 ? dict[phrase] : phrase.charCodeAt(0));
    for (var i=0; i<out.length; i++) {
        out[i] = String.fromCharCode(out[i]);
    }
    return out.join("");
}

// Decompress an LZW-encoded string
function lzw_decode(s) {
    var dict = {};
    var data = (s + "").split("");
    var currChar = data[0];
    var oldPhrase = currChar;
    var out = [currChar];
    var code = 256;
    var phrase;
    for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
        var currCode = data[i].charCodeAt(0);
        if (currCode < 256) {
            phrase = data[i];
        }
        else {
           phrase = dict[currCode] ? dict[currCode] : (oldPhrase + currChar);
        }
        out.push(phrase);
        currChar = phrase.charAt(0);
        dict[code] = oldPhrase + currChar;
        code++;
        oldPhrase = phrase;
    }
    return out.join("");
}
```

this is the code that calls the compressing algorithm and saves it in LS

```
LOG("GetMerchantList(): Done");
    var SITESVAR = unescape(data)
    localStorage.setItem("MYSITES", lzw_encode(SITESVAR));  //this throws error
    IWT.BuildMerchantList(SITESVAR);
```

Comment: if you can give the code so far, then someone can surely guide you

Comment: Provide the code that you are using

Comment: LocalStorage should at a minimum work with a string around 2.5 million characters long (2.5mb in some browsers), and why on earth would you need to store 2.5 million characters in localStorage. This is usually an indication that the the basic idea is wrong.